# Atribuir diretório de um arquivo pesquisado a uma variável CMD

Tags: batch, cmd

Em batch eu consigo pesquisar um arquivo com o seguinte comando:

```
C:\>DIR /S /B PROGRAMA.EXE
```

E se o arquivo for encontrado ele irá retornar assim:

> C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Programa.exe

Gostaria de poder obter no resultado apenas com o diretório sem o nome do arquivo, ou seja apenas `C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\` para poder atribuir apenas o caminho a uma variável.

Há como fazer isso no CMD?

Comment: A resposta te ajudou? Precisa de mais detalhes?

Comment: Ajudou sim, porém não retorna o caminho completo quando o arquivo está dentro de mais de 2 pastas, vou dar um voto na sua resposta pelo trabalho que teve, mas vou publicar a resposta que resolveu o meu problema. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema com esse código:

Opção para atribuir todos os diretórios a diferentes variáveis:

```
@Echo Off
C:
cd /
Set "i=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir/B/S/A-D "Program.exe" 2^>Nul') Do (Set/A "i+=1"
    Call Set "OnlyPath[%%i%%]=%%~dpA")
Set OnlyPath[
Timeout -1
```

Opção para atribuir o ultimo diretório a uma variável:

```
@echo off
set "Working_Folder=C:"
For /F "Delims=" %%F In ('Dir /B /S /A-D "%Working_Folder%\PROGRAM.exe" 2^>Nul') Do (
    Set "MyFolder=%%~dpF"
)
Echo "%MyFolder%" & pause>nul
```

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro criar um batch `mydir.bat`:

```
@echo off
    set MASK=*.java
    for /F %%i in ('dir %MASK% /S /B' ) do (
rem nome de arquivo e extensão (arquivo.txt)
       set FON=%%~nxi
rem extensão (.txt)
       set EXT=%%~xi
rem nome do arquivo (arquivo)
       set PAT=%%~ni
rem unidade e diretório (c:\tmp\)
       set PAT=%%~dpi
rem Imprime localização do arquivo     
       echo %%~dpi
    )
```